# Using else and else if i got the errors

Tags: java, if-statement

```
import java.util.*;
class Example{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input number of employees : ");
        int num = input.nextInt();
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1;i<=num;i++){
                System.out.print("Input Salary : "+i+" : ");
                int sal = input.nextInt();
                sum += sal; 
        }
        System.out.println("Total Salary ; "+sum);
        System.out.println("====================");
        while(sum!=0){
            if(sum > 5000){
                    int r5000 = sum/5000;
                    System.out.println("R5000 : "+r5000);
                    sum %= 5000; 
                }else if(sum > 2000){
                    int r2000 = sum/2000;
                    System.out.println("R2000 : "+r2000);
                    sum %= 2000; 
                }else if(sum > 1000){   
                    int r1000 = sum/1000;
                    System.out.println("R1000 : "+r1000);
                    sum %= 1000; 
                    }
                else if(sum > 500){ 
                    int r500 = sum/500;
                    System.out.println("R500 : "+r500);
                    sum %= 500; 
                }else if(sum > 200){    
                    int r200 = sum/200;
                    System.out.println("R200 : "+r200);
                    sum %= 200; 
                }else if(sum > 100){    
                    int r100 = sum/100;
                    System.out.println("R100 : "+r100);
                    sum %= 100; 
                }else if(sum > 50){ 
                    int r50 = sum/50;
                    System.out.println("R50 : "+50);
                    sum %= 50; 
                }else if(sum > 10){ 
                    int r10 = sum/10;
                    System.out.println("R10 : "+r10);
                    sum %= 10; 
                }else if(sum > 5){  
                    int r5 = sum/5;
                    System.out.println("R5 : "+r5);
                    sum %= 5; 
                }else if(sum > 2){  
                    int r2 = sum/2;
                    System.out.println("R2 : "+r2);
                    sum %= 2; 
                } else if(sum > 1){ //2nd time I used else instead of else if
                    int r1 = sum/1;
                    System.out.println("R1 : "+r1);
                    sum %= 1; 
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

This is my code I got different out put when use else and if else for the lase else if condition:

using else if I got below output but its wrong need to show R1 : 1 as same but when use else i got write answer explain me?

> Input number of employees : 1
>
> Input Salary : 1 : 6
>
> Total Salary ; 6
>
> ====================
>
> R5 : 1

using else/ else if, I got above output but its wrong need to show R1 : 1 as same but when use else i got write answer explain me?

Comment: You entered six as the salary. `sum = 6`. `else if(sum > 5)` is true. You need to enter salary as `2` to get `R1:1`. Your code will have `R1:2` though.

Comment: Your program is in an infinite loop with "else if" because sum=1.

Comment: If you want to regularly create software, you will need some ability to debug program. If you want to become a professional developer, you will *need* some debugging skill. This is a good program to debug. One way is to run the program in a debugger. It allows you to set a breakpoint, at which program execution will pause. From that point, you can run the program one-step-at-a-time. That allows you to follow how the program branches, while monitoring the values of variables. This allows you to see how those values affect the control of the program.

Comment: You might find more advice with Google:  https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+debug+small+programs&oq=how

Comment: I see you are retrieving the modulus of `sum` within each `if` statement. *What exactly is this code suppose to achieve?*

Comment: To add to the comment by @DevilsHnd, including, in the question, a clear statement of what the code is supposed to do is part of writing a good question.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... I got different out put when use else and if else for the lase else if condition ..."*

When *sum* is 1, the *while-loop* will loop indefinitely.

If you use *else*, instead of *else if*, a value of *1* will be matched, and the loop exits correctly.

Since you are repeating the same procedure, just use a *loop*.
This will match each of those conditions, and additionally checks to see when *sum* equals *1*.

```java
int[] sums = { 5000, 2000, 1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 10, 5, 2, 1 };
for (int value : sums) {
    if (sum > value || (sum == 1 && value == 1)) {
        System.out.printf("R%d : %d%n", value, sum / value);
        sum %= value * (sum / value);
    }
}
```

Here are some example outputs,

```
Input number of employees : 1
Input Salary : 1 : 6
Total Salary ; 6
====================
R5 : 1
R1 : 1
```

```
Input number of employees : 3
Input Salary : 1 : 123
Input Salary : 2 : 456
Input Salary : 3 : 789
Total Salary ; 1368
====================
R1000 : 1
R200 : 1
R100 : 1
R50 : 1
R10 : 1
R5 : 1
R2 : 1
R1 : 1
```